# Java poi 3.11 проблема при формировании XLSX

Tags: java, apache-poi

Ситуация следующая: пытаюсь с помощью одного и того же кода создать xlsx файл и поместить его в папку сначала в веб-приложении, а затем в обычном десктопном.

Код:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        for(int i = 0; i < 70000; i++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                Cell cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellValue(i*j);
            }

        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\workbook1.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();            
        workbook.dispose();
```

При этом то, что получается в результате работы веб-приложения, недоступно для открытия в Офисе Майкрософт 2013, OpenOffice - сообщение о неверном содержимом или неверном расширении. Результат работы десктопного приложения открывается без какого-либо сообщения.

Начал копать глубже - открыл оба результата архивом и просмотрел xml - вот что обнаружил:
**xlsx, который открывается**, содержит заголовок: `xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"` и атрибут в корневом теге `xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"`
в **xlsx, который не открывается**:  `... standalone="yes"` и отсутствует атрибут `xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"`

Дальнейший анализ показал, что такое отличие в ряде файлов xml структуры xslx. И это единственное отличие. Следовательно, проблема именно в этом. Кстати, многие xml из xlsx по этой причине не валидны. И еще... использование HSSFWorkbook и получение xls не приводит к такой проблеме. Использование SXSSFWorkbook необходимо, т.к. есть ограничение по памяти, а количество строк может быть более 70000. Как же веб-приложение может влиять на формирование?

Comment: Неужели нет профессионалов в этом вопросе?

Comment: А почему `XSSFWorkbook` не используете?